# Uniform convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I would like some help with the following problem:

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Define $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
f_n(t)=t^n\cdot f(t).
$$ 
Show that if $f(1)=0$, then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, it is a "uniform convergence" problem

Comment: You're right. I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Hint: Extreme Value Theorem + Continuity of $f$ at $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose any positive real number $\epsilon > 0$. The goal is to show that there is an $N>0$ so that $\sup |f_n| \le \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $1$, there exists $0<K<1$ so that on $(K,1]$, $|f(t)| < \epsilon$.

Note that $|f_n(t)| \le t^n |f(t)| \le |f(t)|$. It follows that

$|f_n(t)|<\epsilon$ for $t \in (K,1]$.

On $[0,K]$, $|f|$ attains a maximum $M$. It follows that

$|f_n(t)| \le t^n M \le K^n M$ for $t\in [0,K]$.

Putting the two inequalities together, we have

$|f_n(t)| \le \max(K^n M, \epsilon)$ on $[0,1]$.

From here, you should be able to complete the proof.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Don't you have to explicitly choose a certain N?  2. Suppose that (K^n)M is the max. Then |fn(t)| may be less than or equal to (K^n)M but larger than epsilon. What do you do in this case?

Comment: @JimDarson Those two things are exactly the points that needs to be addressed in order for the proof to be complete. Notice that so far, I haven't said anything about $n$. What happens to $K^nM$ when $n$ gets larger? (Let me know if you want a stronger hint.)

Comment: K^n shrinks when n gets larger,but what does that say about epsilon? If we say that there exists an N so that if n is greater than or equal to n, then (K^n)M is less than or equal to (K^N)M, but that says nothing about the relationship with epsilon.

Comment: @JimDarson $\epsilon$ is a number that was "specified" at the beginning of the proof.  You have the freedom to choose the right value of $N$.

Comment: So you're saying that I can simply choose N sufficiently large, without specifying what N is, so that (K^N)M is less than epsilon?

Comment: @JimDarson You'll need to argue why such a sufficiently large $N$ exists. Note that there are (infinitely) many different values of $N$ that would suffice. If you want to, you can find the exact value where $K^n M$ becomes less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Could a sufficiently large N exist by the archimedian property? That is to say, can I say that there must be an N that is sufficiently larger than n simply by that property?

Comment: You don't need to use the Archimedian property. Remember, $M*K^n$ decays exponentially. It approaches 0 as $n$ gets larger and larger. $\epsilon$ is some positive number.

Comment: Could I use the archimedian property? Wouldn't invoking the property work?

Comment: You probably could, though I'm not really sure what you have in mind. I recommend making a separate post, because in some sense it's a different question, and it doesn't look like anyone else is following up on this post.